# Mover a div conforme o valor do degrees no Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html5, matemática

Simplesmente é mover a div em direção ao valor do degress.

Fiz vários modos, mas não consigo.
Um código que estou tentando: http://codepen.io/duduindo/pen/eNEobG

"Alguém tem alguma luz/solução para este problema?!"

Sinalização/Exemplo abaixo:
[image: Sinalização]

Obrigado!

Comment: Pergunta interessante! Explica por favor o que queres dizer "em direção ao valor do degress"?

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela pergunta. Vamos lá!

É um jogo de 'pipa' em html5 mobile.

Se a div estiver em 45deg, então mover 50px em direção no angulo de 45deg.

Se a div estiver em 300deg, então mover 50px em direção no angulo de 300deg.

Comment: :/ desculpa mas ainda não percebí... como está no teu codepen a div quando clicada vai para o canto direito e nõ faz rotação nenhuma. O que querias que fizesse? eu não conheço p jogo de "pipa"... vou googlar a ver se encontro.

Comment: Opa, então, eu alterei no Code para o melhor entendimento.

Vá na variável **deg** no **js** e muda para um ângulo e da um refresh, após o refresh clica na div vermelha.

Comment: @EduardoFP Mas com essa alteração parece resolvido o problema, não?

Comment: **@bfavaretto** _Mais ou menos_. Neste final de semana eu vou tentar resolver, caso consigo, vou postar o código aqui. Ao contrário, volto a pergunta aqui nos comentários. **:D**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consegui!

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos! :D

Mais detalhes e em execução:
http://codepen.io/duduindo/pen/eNEobG

Somente o código Javascript:

```
function SomenteNumero(v)
{      
  return v.replace(/\D/g,"");  
}

/*
A função vai pegar o valor do rotateZ, mas somente o número.
Exemplo:
    DE: <div id="ID" style="-webkit-transform: rotateZ(320deg);" ></div>
    PARA: 320

Entendeu?! :D
*/
var get_rotate = function()
{
    var z = SomenteNumero( document.getElementById(" ID ").style.WebkitTransform );
    return z;
}

/*
A mágica é nesta função milagrosa! rsrs'

window.body_largura = Largura do body em px.
window.body_altura =  Altura do body em px.
*/
var efeito_ir = function( velocidade )
{   
    var deg = get_rotate(); //Pega o valor do rotateZ atual
    var plus = velocidade; //$velocidade: quanto maior é o valor, maior é a distância. Recomendado é de 10 á 100

    var rotation = deg - 270;
    var dist = Math.sqrt( (window.body_largura * plus)^2 + (window.body_altura * plus)^2);
    var degtorad = Math.PI/180;

    var x = Math.cos(degtorad * (rotation)) * dist;
    var y = Math.sin(degtorad * (rotation)) * dist;

    x = Math.round( document.getElementById(" ID ").offsetLeft + (-x) );
    y = Math.round( document.getElementById(" ID ").offsetTop + (-y) );

    console.log("X: " + (x) );
    console.log("Y: " + (y) );

    document.getElementById(" ID ").style.top = y + "px";
    document.getElementById(" ID ").style.left = x + "px";  

}
```